# How to keep a connection open - C Unix Socket Programming

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I'm trying out socket programming (for Unix) in C for the first time. Is there a way to keep a connection open by using some form of global variable, such as the socket descriptor, which can then be accessed through multiple methods? (So as to eliminate the need of having to call connect multiple times + it is more efficient to have an ongoing connection rather than creating a new one for each operation which has to be carried out).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you have a connected socket (that doesn't get disconnected through some error, etc.), and you don't lose the fd, you can pretty much use it indefinitely. Can you be slightly more specific on what you want?

Comment: Hi @Hasturkun, I have a method in which I create the socket initially, then call the connect function on that socket. I've created a global variable which hold the socket descriptor defined in that method. I then use that (global) descriptor to send more data to the server from a different method (obviously without calling connect, since the connection has not yet been closed). However, the server is not receiving the data sent from the second method.

Comment: If your description is correct, there shouldn't be a problem. are `send()` calls returning errors? I'd suggest tracing the code through a debugger to ensure nothing silly is occurring (e.g. someone overwriting the socket descriptor, or saving a pointer to a function local variable instead of the value, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at TCP Keepalive. It lets you check for dead peers and prevents disconnection due to network inactivity. Example code and a full explanation below:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/